# SVN Server on NFS3 "Database is locked"

Tags: linux, svn, nfs, locks, sunos

Despite a lots of topics about this error, I'm still having trouble with setting up av SVN Server. Server is running on Scientific Linux 6 and repositories are supposed to be stored via NFS3 on a SUNOS Storage server.

I read that mounting with "nolocks" options would solve the problem but I don't want to do so as a lot of users are working at the same time on the server, I guess removing the locks would create new problems.

SVN is installed, working on local files, but when I try to create a repo on distant location, files are created but I get the error "database is locked" and cannot use the repo. I use the fsfs system which is supposed to work fine with NFS.

Would anyone have another option for me ?

Answer (score 0):

OK I eventually set up a new share on the NFS server, accessible by my SVN server only, mounted there with "nolock". Then it works, but not really the point, I still don't know how to set that up without removing the locks.

Answer (score 0):

An NFS client will normally use the NFS Lock Manager (NLM) to synchronize locking of certain files on the NFS server with other NFS client accessing/locking the same files. The *nolock* mount option tells the NFS client not to use the NFS Lock Manager but instead to manage the locks locally on the NFS client machine itself. This is useful if you only have 1 NFS client or several NFS clients where each client works on a different area of the exported file system so that there is no lock contention.

It looks like you have the following:

**(A)** SVN_Client *==>* **(B)** SVN_Server/NFS_Client *==>* **(C)** NFS_Server

Where: Server (B) is *Scientific linux 6* providing SVN services to clients and mounting from Server (C), the *SunOS Storage Server*.

Assuming you have no other machine mounting from the NFS server and providing the same SVN services, the *nolock* option will work correctly as server(B) will do all the lock management locally. There is no need/requirement to lock centrally on the NFS server.

This is true for NFSv3 which you mentioned in your question.